# Pb to use telerik RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: wpf, telerik

I have this code:

```xml
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridViewVisite" 
             ShowGroupPanel="False"        
             Height="250"        
             Width="Auto"
             ColumnWidth="Auto"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Visite, Mode=OneWay}"
             DataLoaded="RadGridViewVisiteDataLoaded" 
             IsReadOnly="True"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"                
             AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
             CanUserReorderColumns="True"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
             RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">

    <telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="TEST_2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

The idea is to have a proper "additional information" row for each row of the first RadGridView.

As you can see the additional information row is currently covering the parent row.
[image: screen]

I'd like to have the additional information ("TEST_2") properly below the row. I suspect the "cause" is AutoGenerateColumns="True"(without automatic feeding it seems to work).

Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the Telerik UI for WPF documentation there are examples how to precisely achieve this: [link](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/row-details/overview)

Answer (score 0):

Actually trouble was caused by a common style:

```
    <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="45px"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
```

As soon as I commented these lines it was normal behavior.